# Pass results of groupby query to a strongly typed view and display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How would I pass the IEnumerable results of this query to a strongly typed view for display?

```
var a = _db.Test
           .GroupBy(g => g.userId)
           .Select(s => new { userid = s.Key,  total = s.Count()});
```

The typical results are:

```
userid = John
total = 2

userid = Joe
total = 5
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a custom class which will be a view model and return List of type of that view model, instead of returning anonymous type:

```
public class MyVM
{
  public string UserID {get;set;}
  public int Total {get;set;}
}
```

and then:

```
var a = _db.Test
           .GroupBy(g => g.userId)
           .Select(s => new MyVM{ UserID = s.Key,  Total = s.Count()}).ToList();
```

and in view:

```
@model List<MyVM>
```

Comment: Good point about materialising the query results via `ToList`.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy i mostly use List of types instead of IEnumerable while making strongly types views and it looks feasable to me.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now. I like the `ToList` option.

Comment: wlecome @luke2012 glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare a concrete type which would be compatible with the results of your query, and pass around a materialised `IEnumerable<T>` (i.e. `T[]`, `List<T>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`) where `T` is the newly declared type.

```
public class TestResult
{
    // Can't be 100% certain about the userId type
    // based on your code sample - adjust as necessary.
    public int userid { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

var a = _db.Test
       .GroupBy(g => g.userId)
       .Select(s => new TestResult { userid = s.Key,  total = s.Count()});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, appreciated.